# 'I am inviting now' or 'I invite now'

Tags: tense

> 1: I invite everyone present to the opening of the new superstore.
> 2: I'm inviting everyone to the opening of the new superstore.

Which of the above most accurately corresponds to...

> 3: *I'm offering this invitation to you now.*

I chose #2 as the correct answer in a test, but the book's answer is #1. Could you please explain it to me why my answer is wrong?

Comment: _I invite everyone present_ - With those words, I am issuing the invitation.  _I am inviting everyone_ can mean _I'm going to invite them_. (I had to think about it first!)

Comment: The ‘now’ in the description is the key. If I am offering it now I can make it to everyone present. The other sentence is less definitive about the time aspect. However, it is a bad question that is poorly structured so feel no shame if it confused you.

Comment: The correct answer is A. But I am lost. If it says "I invite everyone present". It's happening now.

Comment: It is highly suggested that you take some effort to type in the question. It is not like you are asking about each and every question here, it is just one of them.

Comment: Yes, we know the correct answer is A! The words "I invite everyone present" _are_ the invitation, so it's happening now.

Comment: I don't know why this question was summarily closed (because it has a lot of irrelevant text in *images*, whereas we're only actually interested in three lines that should have been presented as *text?*). Whatever - I think even many native speakers could learn something about "performative utterances" here. Why exactly is it that the vicar always says *I **hereby pronounce** you man and wife*, rather than *I **am hereby pronouncing** you man and wife*?

Comment: (I've only just realised that I disagree with the test-setter who thinks the correct answer is #2. An awful lot of online English tests are garbage.)

Comment: Why was it closed? :(

Comment: The post was closed due to lack of context, as stated clearly in the close reason. Antonia, we have been through this before. **Please do not post screenshots of chunks of text. Type it out.** Keep in mind any future posts with such screenshots will be closed. Just so you are aware, community members have raised this issue in a [meta post](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5364/should-we-encourage-discourage-such-indolent-behaviour-from-users).

Comment: Well, it's re-opened now. Someone else can pick up the ball and run with it (but personally I would take some convincing before I would accept that option #2 could reasonably be considered "correct". And regardless of that, I think it's an *appalling* example to present to non-native speakers!

Comment: You can't just copy and paste an image, images cannot be searched. Words, phrases etc. on images are not searchable. Please, next time, make the smallest of efforts to write the question, and never forget to cite your source and include a link where possible.

Answer (score 1):

> I chose #2 as the correct answer in a test, but the book's answer is
> #1. Could you please explain it to me why my answer is wrong?

*B. I am inviting everyone to the opening of the new superstore*

This might or might not be an invitation that is occurring *now*. It depends on the context. Here are two examples to illustrate the difference.

---

1. The manager is making a speech to the employees

*Good news for all of you! I am inviting everyone to the opening of the new superstore!*

This can be considered as being the invitation. However it is actually an indirect statement. From this statement, the employees can infer that they are invited. Maybe they will receive an official invitation at a later date when the details have been finalised.

---

2. The manager is talking on the phone to a friend who lives far away in another country

*Friend: How are you? Is anything exciting happening?*

*Manager: Yes. I am inviting everyone to the opening of the new superstore!*

This is information about the manager's intentions. It is not an invitation to the friend and it is not a "now" invitation to anyone.

---

P.S.

*I am X-ing*  although present continuous, does not simply indicate that something is happening now. It can also indicate future intentions.

Examples

(a)

*A: What are you doing right now?*

*B: I am talking to you!*

*A: Haha - very funny*

(b)

*A: What are you doing next Summer?*

*B: I am going to Australia for two weeks.*

Answer (score 1):

OP's context is what's called a [***performative utterance***.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performative_utterance#:%7E:text=In%20the%20philosophy%20of%20language,social%20reality%20they%20are%20describing.) That's where the very act of saying the words ***does*** something (as opposed to simply *describing* something). Familiar examples include...

> 1: *I **promise** to go*
> 2: *I **name** this ship Boaty McBoatface*

...where simply saying the words is equivalent to ***making*** the promise or ***bestowing*** the name. A good indication that you're dealing with a performative utterance is if the main verb is (or could be) preceded by the word ***hereby*** (which in context effectively means *By **saying** this, I am **doing** it*).

---

OP's test example is poorly chosen, because it pointlessly confuses the idiomatic presentation of performative utterances with the issue of using continuous tense forms (and raises other irrelevant aspects of semantics). So far as I'm concerned, the test-setter in this case should get a different job.

Once we recognise it's asking about a ***performative*** utterance, the obvious way to approach this question is to consider the idiomatically established (not syntactically or semantically dictated) ***general pattern*** of such usages...

> 3: (Vicar) *I **pronounce** you man and wife*
> NOT *I am pronouncing you man and wife*
> 4: (Judge) *I **sentence** you to death*
> NOT *I am sentencing you to death*
> 5: (PR guy) *I **invite** everyone present to the opening of the new superstore*
> NOT *I'm inviting everyone present to the opening of the new superstore*

Comment: I think it's mentioned in Longman English Grammar Practice. It says with declarations we use present simple.

Comment: I'm surprised a dictionary would go down to such a level of detail for an aspect of usage that's not universally applicable. In some contexts, I might classify using the continuous as an *emphatic* alternative: *You say you didn't you do X because you weren't instructed to. Well, **I am ordering you now** to do it*.